# How to remove site collection feature "web template feature of exported web template xxx"

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, site-collection, feature

I have several site collection features that start with the name **web template feature of exported web template**. When I use `get-spfeature` I am unable to see anything with a displayname that matches and I don't have anything in the solution gallery.

I don't think it's causing a problem, but it just bugs me. Does anyone know how to get rid of these?

2 of the features are:

- Web Template feature of exported web template Sales
- Web Template feature of exported web template Marketing

I believe these were created when sites were saved as templates, but I can't verify.

Comment: could you please list the features?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they get created when you save the site as a template. Try using SharePoint client browser and get the Feature ID, then use PowerShell to delete/remove them using -Force attribute.

You can also retrieve feature id from the Site settings page.

```
Site Settings > Site Collection Administration > Site collection features
```

Then use FireBug/IE Developer tool to get the parent element's id of the 'Active' button. Usually, these div id(s) are the guid of the corresponding feature.

Comment: I can't find the Feature Id. I'm looking in the IE developer tool, selecting the 'Activate' button and navigating up items until I find an id that looks like a guid. When I try to uninstall-spfeature -Identity guid, I get an error Cannot find Feature object with id.

Comment: Try stsadm instead. See this link: http://www.sharingminds.com.au/Blog/Post/5/Forcibly-Removing-SP-Features--

Comment: I tried "stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id guid", and got ,"Feature with the id 'guid' is not installed in this farm". I was really hoping that would work.

Comment: I forgot to use the -force. When I did this it says it completed successfully, but the item still shows up in the site collection features list.

Comment: try this tool: http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/